# Why is it that when I login to my Mac there is another login that briefly shows up?

Tags: macos, startup

So, when I log in my cursor will be in one spot, then after I login it will switch to another spot with the same login background and prompt, but then load after that. I only type my password in once.

Comment: Is your chosen display resolution being set upon login?

Comment: @theonlygusti, I don't know.